# Select 2 jQuery Searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using this jQuery plugin http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ with a data source linked to my employe database. The "Term" being used is last name however the jSON response is the full name.

When the result is Smith, John and you type smith it shows fine but when you try to include the first name to narrow it down even more, it stops the search as the comma is not part of the term.

```
$("[name=manager]").select2({
    multiple: false,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeHolder: 'Manager Last name',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: { 
        url: "jsonUser.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term, // search term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
});
```

The jSON response looks like this:
`[{"id":"12345","text":"Smith, John"}`

Anyone know of a way to make is so the full response is searchable and not just the term?

Comment: why dont you parse you data before sending it over a ajax call, to replace ','(comma) with space

Comment: All the Ajax call sends is the last name so there is no comma. The response includes the full name. However, I think the search function only looks at the term entered and not the full response.